# How to enter a Bill as credit in quickbooks using QBXML?

Tags: xml, quickbooks, qbfc

Im trying to enter a bill with QBXML request but I cannot find the way to select the Credit radio button instead of the bill radio button.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
<BillAddRq requestID = "0">
<BillAdd>
<VendorRef>
<ListID>80000012-1628620378</ListID>
</VendorRef>
<TxnDate>2021-05-26</TxnDate>
<RefNumber>TESTING1</RefNumber>
<ExpenseLineAdd>
<AccountRef>
<ListID>80000033-1628622157</ListID>
</AccountRef>
<Amount>52.86</Amount>
<Memo>Testing.</Memo>
</ExpenseLineAdd>
<ExpenseLineAdd>
<AccountRef>
<ListID>80000034-1628627741</ListID>
</AccountRef>
<Amount>10.00</Amount>
<Memo>Also testing.</Memo>
</ExpenseLineAdd>
</BillAdd>
</BillAddRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the `VendorCredit` XML call, not `BillAdd`:

- `VendorCredit`: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/vendorcreditadd

The syntax is *extremely* similar to `BillAdd`, but ever so slightly different.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="15.0"?>
<QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <VendorCreditAddRq>
                        <VendorCreditAdd>
                                <VendorRef>
                                        <FullName >STRTYPE</FullName>                                 </VendorRef>
                                <TxnDate >DATETYPE</TxnDate>
                                <RefNumber >STRTYPE</RefNumber>
    ...
```